# Finding specific caller in composition relation

Tags: java, debugging, composition

```
class MyDate{
    Calendar effectiveDate, cancelDate;
    //Getter and setter
}

class Member{
    private String fName, lName
    private MyDate date;
    //getter setters
}

class Policy{
    private int policyId
    private MyDate date;
    //getter setters
}

class Address{
    private int addressType
    private MyDate date;
    //getter setters
}
```

I have many more classes like Contract, Payment, Address etc. having reference to Date class

Then I have multiple services which calls setEffectiveDate()

```
Service1{
    member.getDate().setEffectiveDate(effDate);
}

Service2{
    policy.getDate().setEffectiveDate(effDate);
}

Service3{
    contract.getDate().setEffectiveDate(effDate);
    address.getDate().setEffectiveDate(addressEffDate);
}
```

I want to set a debug pointer in setEffectiveDate() such that it will suspend execution only when setEffectiveDate() is called on, say Address object.

I tries using Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() but it gives me name of calling Service class (Service3 in this case) but not the actual parent Object(Address) on which the method was called. 
Note: Using Java 7, RSA/Eclipse

Right now I am using a very cumbersome method as follows

```
class MyDate{
    Calendar effectiveDate, cancelDate;
    //Getter and setter
    public String source; //This is temporary variable I introduce just for debugging purpose
    public setEffectiveDate(Calendar effectiveDate){
        this.effectiveDate = effectiveDate;
        /* This is temporary code for debugging */
        if(this.source.equals("address"){
            System.out.println("Called from address"); //Set a debug pointer on this line
        }
    }
}
```

Then later in Address class I set source = "address"

```
class Address{
    private int addressType
    private MyDate date;
    public getDate(){
        this.date.source = "address"; //Temporary code just for debugging
        return date;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First of all the use of the name Date is discouraged as any developer will think it's the standard Java Date class instead of your custom one. I'd recommend you think of renaming it.
Second of all, you can add conditions to break points. In Eclipse you tick the conditional checkbox and then you can add something that will return a boolean like this.source.equals("address") and it will only stop when that condition is satisfied.

Comment: I am using Date, Member, Contract, Service 1, Service2 etc. just for readability and for people to understand, thanks for pointing out though. I have an idea about how to put conditional breakpoint, my problem is what's that condition. BTW there is no such thing as "this.source".

Comment: Ohh I know which "source" you are referring to, but that's the whole point, I don't want to add that temp code (just for debugging) of setting "source" and then checking for it, which I am doing already.